# MATLAB GUI Stuck After Save Tool from Guide

Tags: matlab, user-interface, save, uitoolbar

I have been working on an gui developed using the GUIDE in Matlab. The current gui, I mean the general figure window contains all types of sliders, buttons, editboxes, etc...

After awhile, I added a toolbar to my gui which included the Save tool. I have not changed any specifications regarding the save tool. I used the one already in GUIDE toolbar editor.

After clicking it, my gui program is stuck at that very instance I pressed the save tool and I cannot do anything else with it. It also opens in the same situation even after restarting the PC. I do not get any errors.

I would appreciate any help. How to restore functionality to my gui?

Comment: Can you provide more infos about "the Save tool". Never seen anything similar before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "Save" tool's default is not "Save As" with a prompt it is just the normal "save" which immediately overwrites.  The tool saved your current figure (or GUI).  Meaning it overwrote the fig file of your GUI with the current state.

So when you pressed "save" uicontrol visibility, values, slider positions, edit box text etc. all was written into the FIG file.  So the next time you launch it is all still in there.

To Fix it you will probably have to edit in GUIDE and try to clear / reset everything to your desired initial state.